# Google Web Toolkit Sample Applications

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, javascript-framework

I have googled some time now trying to find a good sample application that is written with the Google Web Toolkit (preferably with Eclipse). I'm looking for a full web application with a database and stuff like the following program on codeplex which is written in ASP.NET and has a login system: 
http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

I found some other sites but they do not contain the exact details that I need:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/project_MySQLConn

http://code.google.com/intl/nl/webtoolkit/examples/

I want to learn GWT because I think it has some great advantages.

1. Generate (good and cross-browser compatible (>IE6, >FF~2.0, >chrome1)) JavaScript at the server-side for the client that will save CPU cycles on the server
2. Use Java at the server (instead of C# with ASP.NET) which is free to use and deploy, and is a good OO language
3. Program and test in other OS's than windows (LAMP server, free :) )
4. Out of the box HTML5 support which can be used as a replacement for flash/silverlight animations to save bandwidth
5. Eclipse has a visual designer plugin (GPE) where you can put widgets on and works like WPF/Silverlight where I have already some experience with
6. The widgets are great and I expect them to work like the WPF/Silverlight equivalents (stackpanels, grids etcetera)
7. Google uses it (so it must be great :P )

Some disadvantages in my opinion:

1. No good support for VS2010 (super IDE of course)
2. Not as many users as ASP.NET or PHP (?) so less good code examples to find
3. Not many I think? Maybe some little debug difficulties because of the generated JavaScript

Please criticize this as much as possible ;)

Comment: you are right, The combination of (e.g.) GWT, RequestFactory and JPA is tricky and I only found basic examples, not complete examples with relation between entities andere so on. Because of this, I think GWT is not that much used as I would expect.

Comment: A complete example with entities is exactly what I would like to check out too. But apparently this is hard to find? I thought I just wasn't looking in the right places ;) Anyhow this surprises me a little since in my opinion GWT should be fantastic and I thought lot's of folks used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT projects are almost identical to other Java-based web applications. Client side has the major differences (and limitations therefore) of course, but everything else is pure Java. Maybe it would be better to start off by learning Hibernate, servlets and such? Find out the best techniques for You and then dig into GWT.

EDIT: I found a really detailed GWT tutorial http://www.vogella.de/articles/GWT/article.html

Comment: So your point is that I could better google for some jsp applications first? Sending widgets to the client is something unique to GWT right? I already check out some hibernate which looks pretty good. It looks like Entity Framework for .NET where I've got some experience with.

Comment: Not necessarily but it would be a good start to know this and that about the basics behind the UI. GWT itself is quite straightforward and indeed similar to other frameworks. The thing about GWT and it being not so widespread is mostly IMO because it's slow first load, thus not suitable for general purpose websites but mostly for narrow groups of people. The thing with these projects is that they often are closed sourced.

Comment: Hmm.. alright then I´ve got no choice but to look through all of the GWT tutorials I guess. Is that what you´d do also? I still find it awkward that there is not even one good project to discover.

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea for starters. They explain the basics quite well actually. I have looked through them too a while back. Anyway, I'll keep my eyes open if I'll see something useful.